# Lambda Expression Where Condition Getting Trouble When String Start With Zero

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

When trying to where condition on string starting with zero linq lambda expression getting trouble and it doesnt work.

`CityCode` field type is string.

For Example:

```
var hospitals=context.Hospitals.Where(p=>p.CityCode=="01");
```

Then it doesnt return any row from database.

But When try this:

```
var hospitals=context.Hospitals.Where(p=>p.CityCode=="21");
```

It works perfect.

How can I achive this problem?

Please help

Comment: No, that code doesn't "work perfect" - it won't compile, as `'21'` isn't a valid character literal. Now, please show the data this is meant to match against. What's the field type in the database? Any reason you're not using a numeric type here?

Comment: Is `CityCode` type of string? then you should use double quotes ("01")

Comment: Assuming that the single quotes are a typo and should be double quotes and that `CityCode` is actually a `string` type in your DB, my guess is that you might have a value like "1", but that's not going to match "01".  It's really not clear what your issue is since we have to make so many assumptions.

Comment: @juharr it is string and recorded in db  as "01".

Comment: @kodcu Are you sure it's a zero and one and not the letter O and a one?  Also you might want to check for unprintable characters in the DB value.

Comment: Yes I am sure its zero

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering this works at all. That depens on the type of `CityCode`

- If you compare `int` values you should use `.Where(p=>p.CityCode== 1);`
- If you compare `char` values `.Where(p=>p.CityCode=='1'); //only one character is valid`
- If CityCode is a `string` then `.Where(p=>p.CityCode=="21");`

Comment: But is string and '01' from the db.

Comment: so `"01"` is sure a string and there are records, fitting this condition in your database?

Comment: @kodcu you seem not to understand the difference between '01' and "01". Please, be precise in what you mean.

Comment: @fubo yes it is string. mixxiphoid I understand. And it is not CHAR it is string.So it will "01"